Origins/Information sought for the words דּוֹק and חֶלֶד, which appear in אַדִּיר וְנָאוֹר - translated as "Heaven and Earth"? (RH/YK Machzor)
I've never seen דּוֹק וָחֶלֶד before except in this prayer. Looking them up hasn't been particularly useful - I can't find a second source that defines דּוֹק as heaven (and can't find any uses in Tanach, but could be another conjugation?), and even though BDB translates חֶלֶד as duration, world, providing excellent Tanach sources, I still consider this an unusual word and am not an etymologist, so I don't really know how to properly research this word.
I am very interested in these two words, so a comprehensive answer would be ideal for being accepted, but happy to upvote any answers that provide some interesting information, especially about the origins of these words, including why they were chosen for this particular prayer.
Maybe research here can help with this question: "Earth" in Tanach

This poem is present in both Ashkenazi and Sefardi rites (at least many of each)

@DoubleAA thank you, I checked a couple of Asheknazi Machzorim and didn't find it. I'll edit the title

in most (all?) Ashkenazi rites it's the very last poem in musaf after vidui.

@DoubleAA can't find it in this one (I am sometimes bad at looking), and happened to be joined by an Ashkenazi this year sitting next to me, who was comparing everything as we went, and he didn't recognise אַדִּיר וְנָאוֹר, although I don't specifically recall looking after musaf vidui

See section 111 https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf_for_Yom_Kippur%2C_The_Ten_Martyrs.111

@DoubleAA thank you. ¿QUIÉN TE IGUALA, OH DOBLE AA?

דוק is likely a reference to Yeshaya 40:22

האזינו כל יושבי חלד

@JoelK that's an incredible theory, well done. How did you figure that out out of interest?

@RabbiKaii I was turning the words דק and שמים over in my head and the relevant fragment from this pasuk came in to my mind, which I then confirmed via Google. It’s in the haftara for shabbat nachamu, so not totally obscure.

you rock @JoelK
